# How to access value of a property of an object within another property of the same obj in c#

Tags: c#, automapper

```
    Mapper.Map<Foo, Bar>(
      o,
      new MyType{
        IntProp = service.GetIntProp(o.someProp),
        StrProp = IntProp == 1 ? "Hello" : "World"
      },
      someOptions => {}
    )
```

Is there a way to just access the value of `IntProp` without creating a variable to hold `MyType`? I could just call the service again, but I am somehow concerned with performance.

Comment: Why not just create the variable?

Answer (score 1):

A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property.
See this question for more details: [Can properties inside an object initializer reference each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29719050/can-properties-inside-an-object-initializer-reference-each-other?answertab=active#tab-top)